# How to list files in CVS attic?

Tags: cvs

If I remove a file from CVS with `rm -v testfile`, `cvs remove testfile` and `cvs commit testfile`, then the *testfile* is moved to attic. I can restore the file from attic with `cvs add testfile` and `cvs commit testfile` commands. However, I need to know the exact file name. How can I list all the files in attic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the repository, you can find all files in the attic with find.  Try a command like:

```
find . -type d -name Attic -exec ls -1 {} +
```

You can also list the files with the `cvs` log command.  Try:

```
log -R
```

Both of these will list the names of the `RCS` files used to store the file.  Remove the `,v` at the end of the file to get the file name you want.